# PHP 5.3 Samesite=none not setting

Tags: php, google-chrome, cookies, setcookie, samesite

I was going to set cookie `samesite` property to `none`.

PHP version is `5.3` and
OS is Ubuntu `12.04`.

Here is code:

```
setcookie("key", "value", time()+30*24*60*60, "/; samesite=None", "mydomain.com")
```

This never worked.

When I changed `None` to `Strict`, `Lax`, or just   (null value), they were all worked.

Only `None` value didn't work.

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Update your php version.

Comment: what does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: @kuh-chan nothing working! cookie value wasn't saved.

Comment: You didn't set the secure flag. From the docs: "If SameSite=None is set, the cookie Secure attribute must also be set (or the cookie will be blocked)."

Comment: @AbuNooh well, I don't think it's possible for me now. PHP, Ubuntu version is very old but site is live and there are a lot of customers.

Comment: @kuh-chan, where can I set Secure attribute? 
When I put Secure attribute, they didn't work. (Strict, Lax didn't work too)

Comment: Does your site run with https and certificate?

Comment: ohh, It's not ssl. Is that matter?

Comment: Great! Btw, does PHP 5.3 support samesite=None attribute?